# Zenity does not show messages in deb preinst when it is ran through Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: package-management, bash, software-center, java

I am creating a deb package which requires java oracle >= 7. So I wrote a simple preinst file with bash script that will pop up a message (using zenity) that will warn the user that he needs to install it. However when the deb package is installed through the Ubuntu Software Centre it crashes before the message pops up. Please help me fix it.

Edit: This occurred on Ubuntu 15.04 64/32 bit.

preinst file:

```
#!/bin/bash

JAVA_VERSION=`echo "$(java -version 2>&1)" | grep "java version" | awk '{ print substr($3, 2, length($3)-2); }'`

 if [[ "$JAVA_VERSION" = *"1.7"* ]] || [[ "$JAVA_VERSION" = *"1.8"* ]]; then
     echo 'java is ok'
     exit 0
 fi

 zenity --error --text="Please install java oracle 7 or newer. \"Ok\", exiting instalation"
 exit 1
```

Install Log:

```
Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 171184 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../usb/test.deb ...
gdk_mir_display_open
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused (zenity:3179): Gtk-WARNING **: 
cannot open display: dpkg: error processing archive /media/test/usb/test.deb (--install):
subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing: /media/test/usb/test.deb
```

Comment: It would be much better to try and add it as dependency of the package. Otherwise, you could examine what existing packages that prompt do (e.g. [ttf-mscorefonts-installer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ttf-mscorefonts-installer), [steam](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/steam). The errors are probably due to it not being able to contact the the display, and because you use `exit 1`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The problem for me was that the message was not displaying. I will edit my description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this option:
'export DISPLAY=:0' needs to be added to the zenity script line.

```
export DISPLAY=:0 && zenity --error --text="Please install java oracle 7 or newer. \"Ok\", exiting installation"
```

But it did not work for me. Strangely it worked every 20th or so test.

The best way for me was to abandon zenity and use debconf. [Debconf tutorial link](http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html). 
Note: the priority of the input window needs to be high or critical or it will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is late but for future reference I can see three immediate problems:

1. You don't set the `-e`flag at the top which is needed for Debconf.
2. You don't source `/usr/share/debconf/confmodule` that must be in all control scripts.
3. The output of `zenity` is not redirected into a variable or anywhere which can interfere with Debconf communication protocol.

Using Debconf is best if it can work.